# Lista país e código

Tags: javascript

Dei uma pesquisada em vários lugares e não achei.
Caso alguém tenha ou saiba onde posso achar um javascript que traga o PAÍS + CÓDIGO DO PAÍS, poderia dar um help?
Preciso pro projeto do e-social, como segue tabela de validação do mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: nao tem como voce transformar essa imgaem em excel e cadastrar na mao no sistema?

Comment: Eu tenho um HTML pronto, mas o código fica muito extenso, como usei o javascript do ViaCep pra cidade/bairro/rua/ibge pesquiser também sobre país mas não achei nada!

Answer (score 3):

No repositório do Github abaixo tem arquivos **json** e outros formatos seguindo a norma [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1),  que especifica a representação dos países nos formatos de 2 letras, 3 letras e código de 3 dígitos

https://github.com/juliolvfilho/lista-paises

Repositório do GitHub, com arquivo **JSON**  de acordo Anexo I Tabela 06 -  Leiautes do eSocial versão 2.4.01;

https://github.com/alexwedsday/tabela06-paises-eSocial

Você pode pegar esse arquivo e carregar na memória como um [Array de Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), ou usar frameworks como: NodeJS ou Angular. Para ler esse arquivo em seu local host.

Um exemplo caso você carregue na memória:

```js
var paises = [{
    "codigo": 13,
    "pais": "Afeganistao",
    "criacao": "-",
    "extincao": ""
  },
  {
    "codigo": 17,
    "pais": "Albania, Republica Da",
    "criacao": "-",
    "extincao": ""
  }
];

function popular() {

  var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < paises.length; i++) {
  
  tbody.innerHTML +=
  "<tr><td>" + paises[i].codigo + "</td><td>" 
             + paises[i].pais + "</td><td>" 
             + paises[i].criacao + "</td><td>" 
             + paises[i].extincao + "</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="popular()">
  <div class="tabela">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Codigo</td>
          <td>Paises</td>
          <td>Criação</td>
          <td>Extinção</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Observação: sempre ofereça um exemplo mínimo em código.

Comment: mas o problema é que esse código do pais nao é igual ao do exemplo, ele quer uma api pro e-social

Comment: Como Júlio disse, os códigos de validação no escocial são diferentes do mencionado. Mas muito obrigado, não conheci, usarei essa em outras aplicações.

Comment: @JulioHenrique ele pediu um help! Mas a partir desse exemplo ele pode criar uma classe e montar essa lista com um Array.forEach  os outros dados são datas de Inserção e Criação

Comment: Se existe essa tabela, então no link http://dados.gov.br/, em alguns lugar deve ter escondido um arquivo no formato *.csv

Comment: @GustavoFreire da uma olhada  acrescentei o arquivo que você estava buscando, utilizei  todas as dicas dos comentários e gerei o arquivo json.

Comment: Acrescentei também como fazer a tabela a partir do javascript. @GustavoFreire

Comment: show de bola @alxwca

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço nenhuma API que você possa obter tais dados.

Creio que seja mais fácil criar uma tabela para consulta.

Use o [SmallPDF](https://smallpdf.com/pt/pdf-para-excel) para converter o PDF e importe os dados em sua tabela.

Comment: Usei o HTML mesmo, também não achei nada referente!

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi o seu comentário. Você quer apenas exibir a tabela que está no  PDF em uma página HTML?